# projection query in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
db.collection('users').findOne({username : decoded.username}, {password:0}).then(user => {
    console.log(user)
});
```

I'm not sure why the output of the user object from console.log still has the password field even after the projection query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new MongoDB nodeJS driver is not supporting this anymore, you could check the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-all-but-the-excluded-fields)

for mongoDB versions > 3.4, you need to use the method `.project()`

so your query will be something like that

```
    db.collection('users').findOne({ username : decoded.username })
    .project({ password: 0 }).then(user => {
        console.log(user)
    });
```